# How to check if year is a leap year

Tags: python

I can't figure out how to use the tk calender ui to print if the year selected is a leap year or no.

```
from tkinter import*
from tkcalendar import*

root=Tk()
root.title("Code project")

selectedDate = Label(root, text="")

def selectDate():
    myDate =my_Cal.get_date()
    selectedDate.config(text=myDate)
    selectedDate.pack()


my_Cal= Calendar(root, setmode = 'day', date_pattern = 'd/m/yy')
my_Cal.pack()

openCal = Button(root, text="Select Date", command=selectDate)
openCal.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

this is the code i have now and it outputs this:

[image] i want to know how to print if it is a leap year or not when the button is clicked

Comment: Are you able to fetch the date from the control?  It looks like you are storing it in your label.  Can you see which characters of that string are the year?  Do you know how to convert that to an integer?  Given an integer, do you know how to compute leap year or not?

Answer (score 0):

A year must fulfill the following criteria for it to be a leap year:

- The year must be evenly divisible by 4;
- If the year can also be evenly divided by 100, it is not a leap year;
  unless
- The year is also evenly divisible by 400. Then it is a leap year.

source: https://www.timeanddate.com/date/leapyear.html

Answer (score 0):

Just create a function that parses the `myDate` variable and extracts the `year` and then use the rules to calculate if it is a leap year.

For example:

```
from tkinter import*
from tkcalendar import*

root=Tk()
root.title("Code project")

selectedDate = Label(root, text="")

def selectDate():
    myDate =my_Cal.get_date()
    if is_leap_year(myDate):  # add text to label to tell user if it's a leap year
        text = myDate + " It is a leap year!"
    else:
        text = myDate + " It isn't a leap year!"
    selectedDate.config(text=text)
    selectedDate.pack()

def is_leap_year(date):   # Check for leap year
    year = int(date.split("/")[-1])
    if not year % 4:         
        if not year % 100:   
            if not year % 400:
                return True
            return False
        return True
    return False


my_Cal= Calendar(root, setmode = 'day', date_pattern = 'd/m/yy')
my_Cal.pack()

openCal = Button(root, text="Select Date", command=selectDate)
openCal.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: How do i get it to print as a label that it is or isn't a leap year

Comment: There's a function [calendar.isleap()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html) in the standard library to check for leap year. if we `from calendar import isleap` the we can replace your call to `if is_leap_year(myDate):` with `if isleap(int(myDate.split("/")[-1])):`

Comment: @Lbozo  the code already does that....